# Does address.send(0) make an actual call or simply return false?

Tags: gas, contract-invocation, fallback-function

Does `address.send(0)` makes an actual message call forwarding some small amount of gas(2300?) to fallback function or does it simply return `false` without making a message call to another contract? It wouldn't be unreasonable to assume that EVM detects 0 value and simply returns false, because what's the point of making a call in this case if there's nothing to send?

I'm asking this, because I want to understand how this example from a [post](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/10/smart-contract-security/) on security works

```
contract auction {
  address highestBidder;
  uint highestBid;
  mapping(address => uint) refunds;
  function bid() {
    if (msg.value < highestBid) throw;
    if (highestBidder != 0)
      refunds[highestBidder] += highestBid;
    highestBidder = msg.sender;
    highestBid = msg.value;
  }
  function withdrawRefund() {
    uint refund = refunds[msg.sender];
    refunds[msg.sender] = 0;
    if (!msg.sender.send(refund))
     refunds[msg.sender] = refund;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Update on 09 December 2019:

As of today, `address.send(0)` returns `true` if call didn't run out of gas. Also it executes the target contract supplying `min(gasleft - 700, 2300)` gas.

Original answer below:

So, when you do `address.send(0)` the return is always `false`. The code inside the fallback function of the called contract doesn't run at all. In the example below I couldn't log a value from inside the fallback function even though there was enough gas to do it.

```
contract A {
    event myLog(bool indexed success);
    function mySend(address B, uint y){
        var success = B.send(y);
        myLog(success);
    }
}
```

---

```
contract B {
    event myLog(bool indexed here);
    function() {
        myLog(true);
    }
}
```

From JS side I did:

- A.mySend(addressB, 0, {gas: 50000, value: 1}); // [success: false]
- A.mySend(addressB, 0, {gas: 50000, value: 0}); // [success: false]
- A.mySend(addressB, 1, {gas: 50000, value: 1}); // [success: true, here: true]
- A.mySend(addressB, 1, {gas: 50000, value: 0}); // [success: true, here: true]